# Error timeout in Linux server when a site is being crawling having "google invisible recaptcha"

Tags: java, google-chrome, recaptcha, chromium

For the past few years I have been crawling the site. Suddenly "google invisible re-captcha" was implemented in a site.

In local machine (window) I got html content but when I run in Linux server "the timeout error" was occur. I've tried 5-10 min wait time but still not working.

Linux Debain (Cenots 7)

- Chrome Version : 92.0.4515.107

  ```
       //String chromeDriverPath = "D:/CodeAxis/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe";// local machine driver path
       String chromeDriverPath = "/root/TestCaseChromeDriver/DriverPath/chromedriver";// linux driver server  path

       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);

       ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       options.addArguments("--headless","--window-size=1920,1200","--ignore-certificate-errors");
       options.addArguments("start-maximized"); 
       options.addArguments("enable-automation");
       options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); 
       options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
       options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); 
       options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation"); 
       options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 
       options.addArguments("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor");
       options.addArguments("--disable-web-security");
       options.addArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows Phone 10.0; Android 4.2.1; Microsoft; Lumia 640 XL LTE) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10166")

       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//if takes this much time to load all components

       driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(140, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  //Time allowed to load the page if not loaded

       driver.get("<SITE_PATH>");
       driver.getCurrentUrl();
       System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());

       driver.quit();
  ```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In principle, recaptcha is intended exactly to prevent crawling, so if the site added it, you should also consider whether that's something you should be trying to defeat; that'll depend on the business relationship (if any), local laws, etc

Comment: *In principle, recaptcha is intended exactly to prevent crawling* Actually it's intended to prevent spammy form submission. I wonder though if it prevents Google crawling it and if not, why not? …